# which version of openssl gives better speed?

Tags: performance, optimization, encryption, openssl

I am using openssl for my encryption work in my project where I encrypt files. The encrytion/decryption process takes too much time. So which version of openssl should I use for better speed? Any lighter version available?

I have also observed that openssl-1.0.2a (latest) gives the worst performance regarding speed. But If I build it with O3 optmization, performance is better. But for lower versions, performance doesn't increase in a considerable amount for optimization. Why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

> which version of openssl gives better speed?

Its dependent upon a number of things, including hardware and and algorithms.

> The encrytion/decryption process takes too much time.

That's kind of relative.

> I have also observed that openssl-1.0.2a (latest) gives the worst performance regarding speed.

But you have not told us your hardware, your algorithm selection or showed us your code...

> But If I build it with O3 optmization, performance is better.

I find `-Os` often gives the best performance because the small code keeps the caches hotter. It depends on the hardware, but I found it to hold true for i386, x86_64, and ARM. There's lots of ARM processors, but the ones I tested are the commoditiy ones used in , for example, Android (5TE and 7/7A).

> So which version of openssl should I use for better speed?

They should all be roughly the same, modulo building with `no-asm`.

---

Also, you need to use the [`EVP_*` interfaces](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption). Its not clear if you have done that.

`EVP_Encrypt` (and friends) ***use*** hardware acceleration, if available. That includes AES-NI on x86_64.

If you use `AES_encrypt` (and friends), then its a software only implementation, and it will ***never use*** hardware acceleration.

---

Also, you need to post the numbers from `openssl speed`. That's the baseline to benchmark with.

---

Finally, Intel has a white paper at [Improving OpenSSL Performance](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/open-ssl-performance-paper.pdf).

Comment: I am using ARM am335x. CFB mode in 256bit keylength.

Comment: When you say "you need to use XYZ interface" where in the stack are you referring to? I'm looking at some code using OpenSSL and it passes a list of ciphers to SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(). I'm trying to use the fastest cipher.